# InteliJ Idea EAP JVM Error

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

i am always using Idea Ultimate EAP always.
recently when i update to new version 162.844.8.exe or 2016.2 (https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+2016.2+EAP)

then getting error

[image]

Let me know what i am missing, if it reistall prevoius version then its working fine.

i've tried setting JAVA_HOME JDK_PATH etc all kind of evoirnment related stuff, even removed that so idea's default JDK or JVM can work. but no luck so far.

Idea download page also say that, in these new version they are using their custom build JDK

*"The installer for Windows now comes with our custom JDK build where we address some issues with focus and font rendering."*

Comment: Besides that, do you have JDK installed on your machine?

Answer (score 0):

Ok its fixed in new version
162.935 or higher

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-157339